# Is "those" a demonstrative pronoun or a demonstrative adjective in this sentence?

Tags: grammar, demonstratives

In the sentence "Their routines are quite different from **those** who live in other countries." is "those" a demonstrative adjective or a demonstrative pronoun?
Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: I don't think the cited text is syntactically valid. It should be something like *Their routines are quite different from **the routines of** those [people] who live in other countries*. You can either compare ***people to people*** ("them", and "people living elsewhere") or you can compare ***routines to routines*** ("their routines" and "the routines of others"). You can't mix the two by comparing people to routines or vice-versa.

Comment: "Their routines are quite different from those of those who live in other countries."

Answer (score 1):

It is a pronoun, because it replaces a noun. It stands for ***people*** or ***persons***.

As an adjective it would have to determine a noun, but in our sentence it can't determine either *routines* or *countries*. It could be an adjective if it would determine an elided noun, but this would presuppose the presence of this noun earlier in the sentence. For example:

> The routines of ***these operators*** are quite different from ***those*** (operators elided here) who live in other countries.

But in your phrase there is no ambiguity, it is definitely a pronoun.

Comment: I don't accept the original sentence as being grammatical. Deletions are governed by rules.

Comment: If the sentence was acceptable, which it isn't (See Edwin's and FF's comments) it would not a pronoun but a **determinative** functioning as a fused determiner-head in NP structure. It's called 'fused' because it combines the roles of determiner and head.

Comment: I see. My English grammar vocabulary is not rich, so I am happy to learn. However, I called it a [pronoun](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/determiners-used-as-pronouns) because the noun which is determined by it is not there. But maybe it is my mother tongue super-precise grammar that is influencing me. :)

Comment: Very well spotted, FF and Edwin, I missed that one!